# How to update dictionary key based on value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have two dictionaries with similar values, but different keys. I'd like to update the second dictionary `db` with the key value of the first dictionary `user`.

What would be the optimal way to do that without overcomplicating logic?

For instance, I have the following dictionaries:

```
user = {'school': ['books', 'pencils', 'sheets', 'notebooks']}
db = {'education': ['books', 'pencils', 'sheets', 'notebooks'],
      'actors': ['student', 'teacher', 'principal']}
```

`user['school']` and `db['education']` have the same list value. I just want to update the key value in `db` with the one found in `user`. The way I thought the implementation is the following:

```
def get_key(my_dict, val):
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if val == value: 
            return key 
    return None

res = {}
for key, value in db.items():
    if value in user.values():
        key_user = get_key(user, value)
        if key_user:            
            res.update({key_user: value})
    else:
        res.update({key: value})

print(res)
```

I am implementing this in Python 3.6.6, so as I understand the order of the dictionary entries is kept.

The desired output would be as follows:

```
{'school': ['books', 'pencils', 'sheets', 'notebooks'],
 'actors': ['student', 'teacher', 'principal']}
```

Comment: What order? BTW I guess you mean None instead of null. Also what happens if you have duplicated values?

Comment: the order of the entry in the dictionary. The base dictionary is `db` which gets updated with `user` dictionary.

Comment: I believe the insertion order is maintained in Python 3.6+, can you add the desired output?

Comment: Dicts are order-preserving only in Python 3.7+ and CPython 3.6.

Comment: Should `user` update `db` with key-values where the values don't match any?

Comment: No, just `db` is getting updated  key from `users`, just the key is updated when the value list is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the order was important I think the easiest way is to re-create the dictionary, not very efficient for larger datasets though.

We can iterate `db` to re-create it, the only thing we need to look at is whether to use the key from `user` or `db`. If the key exists inside `user_values` then we can fetch it's index and use that to get key from `user_keys`, otherwise we use `key`.

```py
user = {'school': ['books', 'pencils', 'sheets', 'notebooks']}
db = {'education': ['books', 'pencils','sheets','notebooks'],
      'actors': ['student','teacher','principal']}

user_keys = tuple(user.keys())
user_values = tuple(user.values())

new_db = {user_keys[user_values.index(value)] if value in user_values else key: value for key, value in db.items()}

>>> {'school': ['books', 'pencils', 'sheets', 'notebooks'],
     'actors': ['student', 'teacher', 'principal']}
```

Comment: No, `index` returns the first occurence of `value`. Besides, what result would you expect if `user's` values aren't unique?

Answer (score 1):

I like [Serial Lazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10208481/serial-lazer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64723322/4518341) with a reversed dict, but the rest is a bit clunky IMHO. I would do a plain for-loop instead:

```
x = {'a': [1, 2, 3]}  # "user"
y = {'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [4, 5, 6]}  # "db"

rev = {tuple(v): k for k, v in x.items()}
result = {}
for k, v in y.items():
    try:
        k = rev[tuple(v)]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    result[k] = v

print(result)  # -> {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [4, 5, 6]}
```

---

Or you could use a [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) if you're fine with reversing all the dicts, converting their values to tuples, then back.

```
from collections import ChainMap

c = ChainMap(*[{tuple(v): k for k, v in d.items()} for d in (x, y)])
result = {v: list(k) for k, v in c.items()}
```

Or just a plain dict:

```
x_rev, y_rev = [{tuple(v): k for k, v in d.items()} for d in (x, y)]
y_rev.update(x_rev)
result = {v: list(k) for k, v in y_rev.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be more efficient if you create a reverse-loopup dict for the `user` dictionary.

Logic reduces to just 2 lines of code:

```
reverse_user = {tuple(user[key]):key for key in user}

new_db_dict = {reverse_user[tuple(db[db_key])]:db[db_key] for db_key in db if tuple(db[db_key]) in reverse_user}

new_db_dict_excl = {key:db[key] for key in db if tuple(db[key]) not in reverse_user}

new_db_dict.update(new_db_dict_excl)
```

Answer (score -1):

We can make it a bit simpler when we realize that we can update the entire `db` with `user`. What we need to figure out is which keys to delete before we update it, while also being careful not to modify `db` when we are iterating it.

```py
user = {'school': ['books', 'pencils', 'sheets', 'notebooks']}
db = {'education': ['books', 'pencils','sheets','notebooks'],
      'actors': ['student','teacher','principal']}

for user_value in user.values():
    for del_key in [db_key for db_key, db_value in db.items() if user_value == db_value]:
        del db[del_key]

db.update(user)

>>> {'actors': ['student', 'teacher', 'principal'],
     'school': ['books', 'pencils', 'sheets', 'notebooks']}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mandera, this differs in the order of the entries, they are reversed.

Comment: Also this adds all keys from `user` to `db`, rather than just the desired ones.

Comment: Yup valid points that were not very clear from the beginning; added another answer